# curl free fields are gradient fields.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I am supposed to show that a curl free field $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ (such that $\nabla \times f=0$) is always a gradient field of some potential $\phi$.

A hint was given by saying that we should try to construct $\phi$ by some line integral. I guess it has something to do with Stokes' theorem.

I think if anybody here could give me a hint how to construct the line integral, I would be able to finish the rest of the excercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathbf{f} = \nabla V$. Fix $\mathbf{x}_0 \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and let $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$. What does the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals tell you about $\int_\gamma \mathbf{f} \cdot d\mathbf{r}$ for any path $\gamma$ from $\mathbf{x}_0$ to $\mathbf{x}$?

Comment: It is $V(x)-V(x_0)$. So yes, this could work, but I thought that this excercise would be somehow more interested in Stokes' theorem.

Comment: OK, suppose that $\gamma$ and $\gamma^\prime$ are two different paths from $\mathbf{x}_0$ to $\mathbf{x}$. What is $\int_\gamma \mathbf{f}\cdot d \mathbf{r} - \int_{\gamma^\prime} \mathbf{f}\cdot d \mathbf{r}$, and why should you care?

Comment: ah okay, then you can add them together to a closed path and Stokes tells you that it is zero. Thank you very much :-)